# Castle Windsor Interceptors - Order?

Tags: castle-windsor

I want to have interceptors executed in a specific order and I bind them to the class using the InterceptorAttribute this way:

```
[Interceptor(typeof(type1))]
[Interceptor(typeof(type2))]
[Interceptor(typeof(type3))]
public class SomeClass {}
```

But unfortunately, it looks like instead of running type1 interceptor, then type2 and type3, castle runs them in some other order. How can I force a specific order? Is it possible?

[update]

I tried with the config file - it seems to work, but I'd prefer an attribute, seems much more easier.

Comment: Instead of using interception, try applying decorators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interceptors applied via attribute are ordered non-deterministically.

The recommended way is to [use the registration API](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-Interceptors-ProxyOptions.ashx).

Comment: I guess you are right so will mark as an answer, but it is a bit disappointing... :(

Comment: @Klotin You could get it working for attributes, with a custom attribute and a `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` implementation.